# GridView paging changing. Capture on postback

Tags: asp.net, page-index-changed

On a page_load() ,

Is there a way of capturing that a paging value has been changed? (e.g.from page 1 to page 2)

This relates to a Gridview control

Answer (score 2):

John - why are you looking for this in the page_load?  You may be better off handling the PageIndexChanged or PageIndexChanging events on the gridview instead.

In the event that you need to know the control that caused the postback during the page_load - look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302/how-to-identify-postback-event-in-pageload) for a solution.  In that solution, they suggest that you query the Request["__EVENTTARGET"] variable.  Another similar solution is [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1380847/2919431.aspx#2919431).

Comment: I want to differentiate between a postback from the PageIndexchanged or a text_changed postback.