# How can I identify, in an ASP.NET Page_Load event, what RadButton initiated a postback?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik, postback

In my ASP.NET page's `Page_Load` I'm trying to determine whether a certain button has been clicked and is attempting a postback:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
    if (Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT") == "doStuff")
      doSomething();
}
```

`doStuff` is a JavaScript within the markup, but I don't want this alone to trigger the `doSomething()` method call, I also need to be able to ensure that the button the user has clicked is correct.

How can I identify and reference the button control from the code behind once the user clicks? I searched for and discovered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302/how-to-identify-postback-event-in-page-load) but when I try to implement it, the control returned is always `null`.

Comment: what you get as `Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET")`?

Comment: The resulting value is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Or use the CommandName and command events.

```
        <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" CommandName="first" CommandArgument="one" OnCommand="CommandHandler" />
        <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton2" runat="server" CommandName="second" CommandArgument="two" OnCommand="CommandHandler" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text="" runat="server" />

protected void  CommandHandler(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    Label2.Text = e.CommandName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really explained what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you would have a much easier time if you added an OnClick event handler to the button instead of trying to figure it out in `Page_Load`. The event handler would only be executed when that button is clicked.